# Quickly sum column of child rows many times in SQL

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite database where I keep track of all the files and directories on my computer. For each file I keep track of the size.
Files and directories are distinguished with a column `is_directory`.

I want to write a query to calculate the size of the all the directories based on the file paths.

For example:

If we have these files:

```
/projects/python/main.py 
/projects/python/util.py
```

Then the directory size of `/projects/python` would be the sum of those two file sizes.

This is easy enough to do for one directory, but how can I do it quickly for all of the folders in the database?

Right now I use a python script to get all of the folders, and then, one by one, I calculate their size with the following.

```
UPDATE files 
SET size = 
   (
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(size),0)
      FROM files 
      WHERE is_directory = 0 AND
      path LIKE '/projects/python%'
   ),
WHERE path = '/projects/python'
```

This works but is slow for lots of directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this sample table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE filesystem(path TEXT PRIMARY KEY, size INTEGER, is_directory INTEGER);
INSERT INTO filesystem VALUES ('/',0,1)
  , ('/projects/',0,1),('/projects/README.md',20,0)
  , ('/projects/python/',0,1), ('/projects/python/main.py',50,0)
  , ('/projects/python/util.py',70,0);
```

This query:

```sql
SELECT path AS directory
     , (SELECT sum(size)
        FROM filesystem AS f2
        WHERE f2.path LIKE f.path || '%' AND f2.is_directory = 0) AS total_size
FROM filesystem AS f
WHERE is_directory = 1
ORDER BY path;
```

will produce:

```
directory             total_size
--------------------  ----------
/                     140       
/projects/            140       
/projects/python/     120
```

Basically, for every directory, it sums up the sizes of all the entries with that directory as a prefix of their path.

---

To update the size of the directory rows instead of calculating them on the fly:

```sql
UPDATE filesystem AS f
SET size = (SELECT sum(f2.size)
            FROM filesystem AS f2
            WHERE f2.path LIKE f.path || '%' AND f2.is_directory = 0)
WHERE f.is_directory = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! That does it. Not the fastest thing in the world, but it does everything I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`.

`Group by` path and in `select` statement use aggregation function `sum()` on size column.

Your query will look something like as show below,

```
Select path, sum(size) from table_name
where path like 'path/python%'
Group by path
```

It will give output as `path and size.`

Now you no need to do iterations over all files.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve my issue. There may be multiple paths like `path/python%` and `/path/javascript%`, etc. This wouldn't output the size for each.